# Independent or Dependent sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample

I am comparing whether Spot Gold prices and Gold ETF prices have the same performance.

A spot price is the current price in the Precious Metals marketplace at which a given asset such as a security, commodity or currency, like Gold can be bought and/or sold for immediate delivery. ETF are traded on stock exchange following gold prices.

I have the sample data for both of them. In this case , are the samples independent  or dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may give a more precise statement of what you mean by $sample$ in your case. Because you are talking about financial data I assume that you are using time-series data. Correct me if you do have some other data format.

If we formalize matters a bit we observe two time-series, one for the Spot Gold prices (call them $\{G_t\}_{t=1...\tau}$) and one for Gold ETF prices ($\{E_t\}_{t=1...\tau}$). If this is the case than it might be pretty unrealisitic to assume that the realisations  at a given time point are independent (either within a time series and between the two time-series).

For me it seems like you need some theory on how the variables are dependent. I.e. if you assume that the Gold price influences the ETF price in the future you could work with a model like

$$\mathbb{E}[E_t|E_{t-1},G_{t-1}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1t+ \beta_2G_{t-1}+ \rho E_{t-1}$$
Here I also added an autoregressive part ($ \rho E_{t-1}$) because typically it cannot even be assumed that the realisations of the same process are independent. You may now test whether your estimate for $\beta_2$ is statistically distinguishable from zero. In case it is, you can argue that the time series are dependent (given some assumptions on the distribution of the error term).

Furthermore, in case you look at time series you fist should check the time dependence within the individual series (use tools like autocorrelationfunctions) and after that you can try to model the dependence structure between the two series. Here, dependening on your goal you have many opportunities, ranging from simple ARMA models to complex VAR  and VECM models that allow for a rich representation of dependencies between multiple time series. Note however that the choice of models and their structural properties may dependend on theory and that there are many further issues with time-series modelling as for example stationarity, autocorrelation in the error terms and so on. For a deeper discussion have a look at this [book](https://www.amazon.de/Time-Analysis-James-D-Hamilton/dp/0691042896).